# VHDL: Getting a part of the actual input in a variable

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I am writing a VHDL code for implementing a cipher on FPGA.

I am passing a hexdecimal value to a signal as an input

```
input :  in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
```

I get the value in input but further I want to use only 1st 8 digits in for loop.

In other words I just need to get a sub-string out of the actual input I receive.
So can I achieve this in VHDL syntax. If yes, can any one provide a hint, or provide any pointer about this.

Comment: Define "digit", i.e. what base?

Comment: *am passing a hexdecimal value to a signal as an input* - No, you are not. You are passing a *value* which is base-agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are passing 64 bits as input (63 downto 0). You can select/work with any number of bits by using the signal name and changing the downto parameters:

temp1 <= input(7 downto 0); -- This maps 8 LSBs of input to temp1

temp2 <= input(15 downto 8);

temp3 <= input(63 donwto 56); --This maps 8 MSBs of input to temp3

Answer (score 1):

This is basic HDL — if you want to work on a subset of a signal, just specify the range you want to work on, such as:

```
input(3 downto 0)
input(7 downto 4)
input(11 downto 8)
. . .
```

If you want to do the same thing to different subsets, there are various [looping constructs](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/for_loop.html) that you can use to simplify the source code.